# What's the meaning of some members in SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, msdn

I have looked it up in MSDN , but it only lists the meaning of some members . 
Here is the link in MSDN
[SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx)

You see,there is not a indication of the meaning of `PVOID Reserved2[3]`,.And on my book , in a example of hooking the `NtQuerySystemInformation` function to hide a process , some code like below

```
if(!_tcsicmp((PWSTR)pCur->Reserved2[1],g_szProcName)) //pCur points to a SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION , g_szProcName variable is the name of the process to hide . According to the book , here is to search for the target process to hide.
{
   // something to do . According to the book , here is to delete the node of the process to hide  in the single linked list of  SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure 
}
```

As you see , here use the the member `PVOID Reserved2[3]` of this structure . I guess it is the name of the process . But in the code it use `Reserved2[1]` , so I want to know the accurate meaning of it and other members not mentioned in MSDN , anyone can help me?

Comment: Which book is this ?

Comment: Problems with your malware project .......

Answer (score 4):

The reserved stucture members are usually not intended to be used by non system programmers (i.e. not intended to be used by you).  They are usually described (in the MSDN) as

> Individual members of the structure are reserved for internal use by the operating system.

Reason is, that the content/use of those fields are not guaranteed to stay the same (i.e. Microsoft reserves the right to change the content/meaning of those fields, e.g. with the next operating system).

In your book, someone may have determined/debugged what exactly is in those fields and is acting on that knowledge.  But if you write a program that makes use of this knowledge, the program is not guaranteed to work with later (or even other) versions the operating sytem.

Comment: It's not even guaranteed to work with the _same_ version of the OS. A particular field may contain one variable at one moment and another variable at another. IOW, the field in reality might be a `union`.

Comment: Yes or there is no guarantee that the book interpreted it correctly (or missed cases where the meaning was different).